# Access - Add Left Join to Return Value Based on Primary Key (PK)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help querying a user name based on its primary key value in table.

Another user @gordon-linoff helped me create a query to pull the most recent `NoteDate` for every `OpportunityID` in a table.  I wanted to expand this to provide the `NotesUser`, which is part of the same table as the other two elements.

My challenge is `NotesUser` returns the `UserID` (which is a PK) and not the `UserName`.

Here is an example.  This code:

```
SELECT o.OpportunityID, n.NotesDate, n.NotesID, n.NotesUser
FROM (Opportunity AS o LEFT JOIN (SELECT n.* FROM tblNotes AS n WHERE n.NotesDate = (SELECT MAX(n2.NotesDate)
                            FROM tblNotes as n2
                           WHERE n2.OpportunityID = n.OpportunityID
                           ))  AS n ON o.OpportunityID = n.opportunityid) 
ORDER BY o.OpportunityID;
```

Produced this result:

[image]

`NotesUser` is the PK of a table called `tblUsers`, which contains two columns.  `ID` and `UserName`

Here the code I've got so far

```
SELECT o.OpportunityID, n.NotesDate, n.NotesID, n.NotesUser, tblUsers.UserName
    FROM (Opportunity AS o LEFT JOIN 
         (SELECT n.* 
          FROM tblNotes AS n 
          WHERE n.NotesDate = (SELECT MAX(n2.NotesDate)
                              FROM tblNotes as n2 
                              WHERE n2.OpportunityID = n.OpportunityID)
              AS n ON o.OpportunityID = n.opportunityid) LEFT JOIN 
                                                                (SELECT tblUsers.UserName
                                                                 FROM tblUsers 
                                                                 WHERE n.NoteUser=tblusers.username) 
    ORDER BY o.OpportunityID;
```

This code throws a syntax error in the FROM statement.

Update: Here is what the tblUsers looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just add a `LEFT JOIN`.  No subquery is necessary:

```
SELECT o.OpportunityID, n.NotesDate, n.NotesID, n.NotesUser,
       u.username
FROM (Opportunity AS o LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT n.*
       FROM tblNotes AS n
       WHERE n.NotesDate = (SELECT MAX(n2.NotesDate)
                            FROM tblNotes as n2
                            WHERE n2.OpportunityID = n.OpportunityID
                           )
      )  AS n
      ON o.OpportunityID = n.opportunityid
     ) LEFT JOIN
     tblUsers as u
     ON n.NoteUser = u.id
ORDER BY o.OpportunityID;
```

Comment: This code throws a type mismatch error, which kind of makes sense since `NotesUser` in `tblUsers` is a short text data type.  My comment about NotesUser being a PK was confusing.  Sorry.  u.ID is an auto generated number.  I need something to resolve the `NotesUser` into the actual `UserName` in `tblUsers`.

Comment: So use the `INT()` function to match them.  You really should fix the tables so the ids have the same type.

Comment: That definitely worked.  Thanks.  Tried troubleshooting my table, i.e. get the table to save the user's name and not the user's ID.  Didn't get very far.

Comment: Fixed it.  Thanks for the help.